# Browser automation: Python + Firefox using PyXPCOM

Tags: python, firefox, automation

I have tried [Pamie](http://pamie.sourceforge.net/) a browser automation library for internet explorer. It interfaces IE using COM, pretty neat:

```
import PAM30
ie = PAM30.PAMIE("http://user-agent-string.info/")
ie.clickButton("Analyze my UA")
```

Now I would like to do the same thing using [PyXPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/pyxpcom) with similar flexibility on Firefox. How can I do this? Can you provide sample code?

**update: please only pyxpcom**

Comment: Chill dude. There's a lot of people out there who start off a question by assuming they already know the answer. Sometimes the best solution is not the one they're focused on. Since you make no mention of WHY you need PyXPCOM over the many other automation options it does no harm to provide alternatives you may not have considered. Sooner or later someone with PyXPCOM experience will give you the answer you need, if not then the other answers don't matter. At the very least they may solve the problem for other users who stumble on your question searching for 'browser automation'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've used [webdriver](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/webdriver/0.5) with firefox. I was very pleased with it.

As for the code examples, [this](http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/wiki/PythonBindings) will get you started.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding of PyXPCOM is that it's meant to let you create and access XPCOM components, not control existing ones.  You may not be able to do this using PyXPCOM at all, per Mark Hammond, the original author:

> [It simply isn't what XPCOM is trying to do.  I'm not sure if Mozilla/Firefox now has or is developing a COM or any other "automation" mechanism.](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2004-October/002569.html)

and:

> [If by "automating", you mean "controlling Mozilla via a remote process via xpcom", then as far as I know, that is not possible](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Mail/Message/pyxpcom/3506917)

You may instead want to take a look at the previously-suggested Webdriver project, [Windmill](http://www.getwindmill.com/), or [MozMill](http://code.google.com/p/mozmill/), both of which support automating Firefox/Gecko/XULRunner via Python.

Answer (score 2):

If you're testing a webapp and want to write Python to do it, check out [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) so you can use the same API for all browsers.